Can PyMuPDF be used to make a form field visible and printable?
Is it possible to change the setting (programmatically with PyMuPDF) that allows PDF form fields to be printable? I have been able to read and manipulate form field content, style, and appearance but have been unable to change the field setting to "Visible" from the apparent default value of "Visible but doesn't print." I can change this setting manually with Adobe Acrobat Pro (see below), but have been unable to identify an automated way to do this.
Flattening the PDF makes the file contents printable but renders the form no longer fillable. These forms will be provided to users who will submit data and may also wish to print the form.
Any solution that is supported by PyMuPDF or is automated and works within Adobe Acrobat Pro would be welcome. Thank you.

EDIT
Building on @KJ's example file with four Text form fields, each reflecting one of the possible values. PyMuPDF (1.24.10) returns widget.field_flags = 0 for all of them.
import fitz
fname = 'fieldstates.pdf'
pdf = fitz.open(fname)
for page in pdf:
    widgets = page.widgets()
    for widget in widgets:
        print('********************')
        print('field_name\t', widget.field_name)
        print('field_flags\t', widget.field_flags)


********************
field_name       Text1
field_flags      0
********************
field_name       Text2
field_flags      0
********************
field_name       Text3
field_flags      0
********************
field_name       Text4
field_flags      0


@KJ Thanks for the example file. It appears as expected in Adobe Acrobat Pro. However, when I use PyMuPDF (1.24.10) to obtain the widget.field_flags, field_flags is 0 for all four text widgets.

@KJ It appears that this property is in widget._annot.flags, not widget.field_flags. The expected values of 4, 6, 0, and 36 are returned when reviewing _annot.flags. I will explore setting this in _annot.flags and create an answer when resolved. Thank you for your assistance.
